# Is there a way to cast a federated value?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

If I have a federated value, say `{int32}@CLIENTS` that I'd like to cast to `{float32}@CLIENTS` is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensor manipulating generally needs to occur inside a function decorated with [`tff.tf_computation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/tf_computation). Since the types mentioned have placements (`@CLIENTS`) this likely is inside a [`tff.federated_computation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_computation) decorated function, so the casting method would need to be called with [`tff.federated_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_map).

Something like this:

```py
@tff.tf_computation
def cast_to_float(x):
  return tf.cast(x, tf.float32)

@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType(int32, tff.CLIENTS))
def my_func(a):
  a_float = tff.federated_map(cast_to_float, a)
  return a_float

print(my_func.type_signature)

>>> ({int32}@CLIENTS -> {float32}@CLIENTS)
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be done using tf.cast(), however using @tff.federated_computation().